# How do I copy a folder structure with only modified files on GIT?

Tags: git, move, patch

I have this repository with a big folder structure and a lot of files. I need to take only modified files without a commit and copy to another folder, with same folder structure.

Have someone done something like that?

Comment: Do you need everything in the last commit+the diff, the diff only or the files that were modified?

Comment: [Please try to improve your spelling.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362)

Answer (score 0):

I've solve this by simple PHP code, when you run it, all changed file will be copied on patch folder.

$dir = dirname(**FILE**) . "/";
$patch = dirname(**FILE**) . "/patch/";

cp($dir, "", $patch);

function cp($dir, $file, $patch) {

```
if ($file == "patch" || $file == "index.php")
    return;

if (is_dir($dir . $file)) {
    $patch = $patch . $file . "/";
    $dir = $dir . $file . "/";
    $files = scandir($dir);

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            cp($dir, $file, $patch);
        }
    }
} else {
    $t = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));


    if (filemtime($dir . $file) > $t) {
        if (!file_exists($patch))
            mkdir($patch, 0777, true);

        copy($dir . $file, $patch . $file);
    }
}
```

}